# Sending Airflow logs to grayLog using fluentd

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, fluentd, graylog

I need to send logs of airflow containers to the grayLog using fluentd.
How to do it?

I didnt find any good documentation on it.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm also trying to send Airflow logs to fluentd